# Prevent spring from injecting the default AuthenticationManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a spring security configuration with two different AuthenticationProviders and exposing a rest interface to verify credentials (this is just used in the dev environment and will be replaced by an oAuth service in prod.) But when I inject the AuthenticationManager into the Controller, spring creates a default AuthenticationManager and injects it into the RestController. How can I make spring inject the AuthenticationManager configured in the WebSecurityConfigurationAdapter? I'm using spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.7.RELEASE. Here is my security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@Configuration
public class LocalWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final DevUserDetailsService devUserDetailService;
    private final ServiceUserDetailService serviceUserDetailService;

    @Autowired
    public LocalWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter(DevUserDetailsService devUserDetailService, ServiceUserDetailService serviceUserDetailService) {
        this.devUserDetailService = devUserDetailService;
        this.serviceUserDetailService = serviceUserDetailService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint())
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint() {
        return (request, response, authException) -> response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(devUserDetailService);
        DaoAuthenticationProvider serviceUserAuthProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        serviceUserAuthProvider.setUserDetailsService(serviceUserDetailService);
        serviceUserAuthProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        auth.authenticationProvider(serviceUserAuthProvider);
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

And here is my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/login")
public class LoginController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public LoginController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Map<String, String> login(@RequestBody Map<String, String> body) {
        String user = body.get("user");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, body.get("password"));
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            return Collections.singletonMap("status", "ok");
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            return Collections.singletonMap("status", "bad credentials");
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            log.warn("Could not authenticate user {} because {}.", user, e.getMessage(), e);
            return Collections.singletonMap("status", "general error");
        }
    }
}
```

And since you guys are probably experts in spring, is there a best practice to create different security configurations depending on the environment (using the profile) the code is running on without creating redundant code? I tried a super class, but spring didn't like that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. By using configureGlobal inside my configuration class the AuthenticationManager gets shared across all spring managed Components.

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, DevUserDetailsService devUserDetailService,
                            @Qualifier("serviceUserAuthenticationProvider") AuthenticationProvider serviceUserAuthProvider) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(devUserDetailService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(serviceUserAuthProvider);
}
```

For reusing configuration, I still didn't find a good solution. Creating an abstract “super configuration” for all the common configuration is creating troubles as soon as a method is annotated with @Bean and creating multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter results in one overwriting the other, so if there is a best practice, I'm still interested in a proper solution. I've managed to do what I wanted, but it still feels like a little of a hack to me. For anyone stumbling across a similar issue I hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the bean in `LocalWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter`:

```
@Bean(name="appAuthenticationManager") 
@Override 
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {  
       return super.authenticationManagerBean(); 
}
```

and inject it other components just like any other bean:

```
public LoginController(@Qualifier("appAuthenticationManager") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}
```